# Saber quantas posições foram preenchidas em um vetor em C

Tags: c, array

Não consigo exibir as posições preenchidas em C. Preciso que me retorne quais posições faltam para serem preenchidas e as que estão preenchidas.

ex:"Até o momento existem 3 alunos cadastrados, possibilitando assim a inserção de, no máximo, mais 7 alunos."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <locale.h>

int main(void){
    set locale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    printf("###################### ENTRE COM OS DADOS ABAIXO ##########################\n\n");
    //chamada da function
    imprimemenu();

    return(0);
    system("pause");
}
    struct Alunos{
        char name[10];
        char sobrname[10];
        int matri;

        //variavel data de nascimento
        unsigned int dia,mes,ano;

        //data atual que o ussuario digitar
        unsigned int atualDay,atualMonth,atualYer;

        unsigned int resultDia,resultAnos;
    };

//funcoes do algoritmo;
imprimemenu(void){
    unsigned int esc;
    do{
        printf("Menu de Opções:\n");

        printf("1-Cadastrar Aluno:\n");
        printf("2-Calcular Idade:\n");
        printf("3-Imprimir Aluno:\n");
        printf("4-Pesquisar Aluno:\n");
        printf("5-Excluir Aluno:\n");
        printf("6-Esvaziar lista de Alunos:\n");
        printf("7-Quantidade de Alunos cadastrados:\n");
        printf("0-sair:\n");
        scanf("%i",&esc);
            switch(esc){
            case 1:
                system("cls || clear");
                printf("DIGITE ABAIXO OS DADOS:\n");
                inseriraluno();
                break;
            case 2:
                system("cls || clear");
                //agestudents();
                break;
            case 3:
                system("cls || clear");
                listalunos();
                break;  
            case 4:
                system("cls || clear");
                //searchstudents();
                break;
            case 5:
                system("cls || clear");
                //excluirstudents();
                break;
            case 6:
                system("cls || clear");
            case 7:
                system("cls || clear");
                contstudents();
                break;
            case 0:
                system("cls || clear");
                printf("PROGRAMA FINALIZADO PELO USUÁRIO!\n\n");
                break;
            default:
                system("cls || clear");
                printf("NENHUMA OPÇÃO SELECIONADA!\n\n");
                printf("POR FAVOR SELECIONE UMA DAS OPÇÕES ABAIXO\n\n");
                imprimemenu();  
            }
    }while(esc);
}
inseriraluno(){
    int conta = 0;  
    //definindo o nome da minha estrutura
    struct Alunos alunos[10];

    //data do dia do cadastro do usuario;
        printf("\nDIGITE A DATA DE HOJE:");
        printf("\nDigite o Dia:");
        scanf("%d",&alunos[conta].atualDay);

        printf("\nDigite o Mes:");
        scanf("%d",&alunos[conta].atualMonth);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nDigite o Ano:");
        scanf("%d",&alunos[conta].atualYer); 

    for(conta = 0; conta<1; conta++){
        fflush(stdin);

        //dados do usuario
        printf("\nDigite o nome do %d Aluno:",conta+1);
        gets(alunos[conta].name);

        printf("\nDigite o sobrenome do Aluno:");
        scanf("%s",&alunos[conta].sobrname);    

        printf("\nDigite o numero de matrícula do Aluno:");
        scanf("%d",&alunos[conta].matri);


        //data de nascimento do usuario
        printf("\nDIGITE A SUA DATA DE NASCIMENTO:");
        printf("\nDigite o Dia:");
        scanf("%d",&alunos[conta].dia);

        printf("\nDigite o Mes:");
        scanf("%d",&alunos[conta].mes);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nDigite o Ano:");
        scanf("%d",&alunos[conta].ano);

    }
}

contstudents(struct Alunos alunos[10]){
    unsigned int contador;
    unsigned int total = 0;
    unsigned int resto = 0;
    for(contador = 0; contador<alunos; contador++){
        printf("O tamanho é: %d\n\n",sizeof(alunos[contador]));

        return 0;
    }
    //printf("\n\nAté o momento existem %s alunos cadastrados, possibilitando assim a inserção de, no máximo, mais "" alunos.",total;   


}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Esse código tem muitos erros (alguns não impedem o código de funcionar, mas não é o jeito certo de fazer), eu não vou tentar consertá-los porque praticamente teria que reescrever tudo. Para resolver essa questão existem basicamente duas saídas:

1. Manter uma variável contadora e ir incrementando ou decrementando conforme for inserindo ou removendo estudantes. Até pode criar uma estrutura para manter essa variável junto do *array*, seria a forma mais profissional.
2. Colocar um caractere nulo no início (pode ser em qualquer lugar) de cada elemento do *array* quando o inicializa e vai sobrepondo quando insere, e quando remove, põe de volta o caractere nulo ali. Assim pode andar elemento por elemento e vai contando como fez na função `contstudents()` (nome ruim) usando um `if` para verificar se chegou onde tem um nulo, quando encontrar um nulo, para de contar porque não tem mais elementos.

Note que remover não é uma operação tão simples como pode parecer, provavelmente teria que rearranjar todo o *array*.

Comment: Obrigado bigown, estou modificando o código com vc me sugeriu. Como sou iniciante em C, estou apanhando para fazer esta função funcionar. Você poderia enviar um exemplo ?

Comment: Como eu disse para fazer um exemplo eu teria que reescrever o código, não estou com paciência para fazer isso. Nem é o objetivo do site. Se apergunta fosse mais específica talvez até daria.

Comment: Consegui aqui. Obrigado pela ajuda ai.